# Remove URL prefix in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an S3 URL like so:

`https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/1c4248b2-4256-4af4-ac1b-0e1e3f7ec2c8/filename.jpg`

What I'd like to do, is, using Ruby, remove the prefix `https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/` leaving only `uploads/1c4248b2-4256-4af4-ac1b-0e1e3f7ec2c8/filename.jpg`.

I'm unsure whether using gsub and just replacing the prefix (hardcoded) with empty space is the right way to go – or, if there's a more efficient approach.

`url.gsub('https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URI` from ruby's standard library:

```
irb> require 'uri'
=> true

irb> u = URI("https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/1c4248b2-4256-4af4-ac1b-0e1e3f7ec2c8/filename.jpg")
=> #<URI::HTTPS:0x000000020995f0 URL:https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/1c4248b2-4256-4af4-ac1b-0e1e3f7ec2c8/filename.jpg>

irb> u.path
=> "/uploads/1c4248b2-4256-4af4-ac1b-0e1e3f7ec2c8/filename.jpg"
```

Alternatively `u.request_uri` returns any parameters on the URI too.